# jquery ajax events with classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this code:

```
$('.be-delete').live('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var object =$(this);
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $.ajax({
        url : url,
        error : function(){alert('An error has occurred, no updates were made')},
        success : function(){
            object.parent().fadeOut('slow', function(){object.parent().remove()});
        }
    });
});

$('.be-delete').ajaxStart(function(){
    $(this).parent().html('<img src="' + base_url + 'media/images/jquery/spinner.gif' + '"/>');
});
```

the problem is $(this) on the ajaxStart callback is not working and all li's are affected! my html markup is as follows:

```
<li><img src="1.jpg"/><a class="be-delete"href="#">Delete</a></li>
<li><img src="2.jpg"/><a class="be-delete"href="#">Delete</a></li>
<li><img src="3.jpg"/><a class="be-delete"href="#">Delete</a></li>
```

how do I capture the ajaxStart event for only one li?

Comment: Any feedback on my answer? Does it do what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this. This sets a data attribute on the clicked element. Thus you can identify in `ajaxStart` which `li` really was clicked.

```
$('.be-delete').live('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var object =$(this);
    object.data("clicked", "yes");
    ...
});

$('.be-delete').ajaxStart(function(e) {
    var ele = $(e.target);
    if(ele.data("clicked")=="yes") {
        ele.removeData("clicked");
        ele.parent().html('<img src="' + base_url + 'media/images/jquery/spinner.gif' + '"/>');
    }
});
```

Btw. just as a note. You should do this a bit differently. As in the ajaxStart you set the innerHTML of the parent div to show the spinner. But what are you going to do when the ajax request fails? The original content of the `li` is lost and the li will still display but now only showing the spinner instead of the original content.

Answer (score 0):

ajaxStart is a broadcast event sent to all items subscribing to it. i think your best bet is to record in a global the element that was clicked, and then in the ajaxStart handler perform your img swap using that object alone, not the element(s) receiving the start event